# Retrieve User ID using WinJS

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have an app that performs a calculation, and I need to store this results in a database via webservice. I need to store this results with some user identification, in a table structure like this:

user_id| test_result

The problem I have is that I don't know how to obtain the "user_id". Is there an API that simply retrieves the store username/e-mail? If there's not, What's the simplest approach?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a class in WinRT that will give you the users name (domain name and display name):

Take a look at
[Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241871.aspx)

Or you could use a third party authentication, like a Facebook login. There's an app sample for that at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122

Comment: for a unique id though, UserInformation won't be too helpful unless you use the PrincipalName, which requires Enterprise Authentication capability (and a company store license).  Third party may be better OR [ASHWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/jj553431) perhaps?

Comment: Another thought would be one of the hardware tokens from Windows.System.Profile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.aspx